# Lock transaction and release it when an admin confirms it with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, transactions, doctrine

I am doing a project with Symfony 3 and I need that an admin confirms all the transactions in the database (insert, update and delete) and then release them.

I have a form and when I do some transactions (for example update something), it will update. I need that it doesn't update, but rather it blocks and it will update if an admin confirms it.

Some idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: I debugged the application from the preUpdate to the postUpdate but I  didn´t find how it can be lock. I saved the old versions of the entities too (for example if I update a customer, I saved the old version of the customer in a table in the db, but it is not the sense of the application.
PS: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You have Doctrine behaviors to track the changes made on a given entity: http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/behaviors.html#versionable

Comment: With the behaviors i can have a versioning of the transactions, but if I update something, it will be updated (the old version will be saved, but the original version will be the new one). It means that the update will be active before the admin confirm it :(

Comment: Is not possible to block the transaction and then release it anyway?

Comment: I never saw this before, I don't think Doctrine can handle this. Create a "transaction" table, that you will "validate" in a back office.